# Learn SSRS SOAP API in C# language

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, c#-3.0

Where do I start learning SOAP API based on C# for Reporting Service ? MSDN articles are difficult for me to understand and ended up making me confused. In fact, they are like giving more facts. I want to get my hands dirty on coding. But I don't know where could I start. What I want to do is I want my RDL reports/or RDLC reports to get accessed by users over the web. Please give me some guide.
P.S My coding skill is not very good ,but I want to learn more and practise more to improve it. Currently I am using SQL 2012 and VISUAL STUDIO 2012. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way was to start with generated proxy class. I did that using this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx). Follow the section named "Adding the Proxy Using the WSDL Tool". According to it, first generate proxy class running this in command prompt (you may need to use VS dev command prompt to run wsdl.exe):

```
wsdl /language:CS /n:"Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010" http://<Server Name>/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl
```

You will get ReportingServices2010.cs file, which you can include in your projects and use to connect to SSRS server.

```
var service = new ReportingService2010(){
   Url = "http://<your server>/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx" // url to your server
};
```

Then you can code anything you want according to MSDN documentation on this reporting service.

Let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you made progress since your post (I hope so), but in my case I use the SOAP web service, without created proxy server by hands. VS will do the job.
This [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/report-server-web-service) and related links explain it.

The principle is the following : access the SOAP web service through an URL that looks like that : http://server/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl

where "server" is your domain name server, or IP address 
and "reportserver" the access point of your SSRS server (it can be different in function of your installation settings).

After, in your VS, go in "Project" menu and choose "Add a service reference". Then enter the URL of your SSRS SOAP service (as explained before) and that's it !
It will create a new folder in your project called "Web Reference" with a item inside, directly linked to yout web service.

Then you can us it like any other object of .NET Framework (by creating ReportingService2010 for example like done in previous post).

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Regards